# unable to replace <p> </p> with <p>&nbsp;</p>

Tags: javascript, regex

Using native javascript i am unable to get a `string.replace("<p> </p>", "<P>&nbsp;</p>");` to work, it seems like it wont find anything to replace.

when i get the outerHTML or innerHTML of the

element it returns with a standard space character " " and i need to get the `"&nbsp;"` version of the space.

How would i go about doing this. I've tried to write a regex to do it but it seemed that the regex wouldn't find anything to replace either, and i know there's at least 3-4 of them on the page.

Comment: Matching html with RegEx? I'm sure you'll find the solution to your problems [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)... :-)

Comment: It does work, yet it only replaces the first occurence. You'd have to use a regex with the *global* flag (`/<p> <\/p>/g`), but it's [no good idea to match html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572) (though it might work for this specific, simple case).

Comment: [You shouldn't parse XHTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

It does work, yet it only replaces the first occurence. You'd have to use a regex with the *global* flag (`/<p> <\/p>/g`) for [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), but it's [no good idea to match html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572) (though it might work for this specific, simple case).

The DOM way would be cleaner:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var i=0; i<paragraps.length; i++)
    if (paragraphs[i].innerHTML == " ") // does not contain other empty elements
        paragraphs[i].innerText = "\uA0";
```